# Sync Ubuntu computer with Virtual Machine instance of Ubuntu

Tags: virtualbox, sync

Here is my situation. I have a laptop with Ubuntu 14.10 installed that I do my work on the go and I have now set up a VM of Ubuntu 14.10 using Virtual box installed on my Windows Desktop. I'm wondering if there's any way to sync the VM running Ubuntu and the Laptop running Ubuntu together (including files, programs, etc). I pretty much want the exact OS on both my laptop and VM and any changes made on one will change on the other.

Comment: rsync leaps to mind. You'll need to be careful to only include the information you actually need synced as the hardware each system sees is completely different and there may be specific configuration files that must be different. By files I assume you mean the content of /home by programs you likely mean the content of /usr/bin. /sbin is likely already identical provided both systems are updated. You might be better off using remote access from the VM to access the laptop in which case you'd actually be using the same system rather than syncing it.